# How do I select all the links that has an immediate img tag in it using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html,

```
 <div id="sec">
     <a><img /></a>
 </div>
```

how do I select all the links that contains an immediate img tag in it in this div with id="sec" using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div#sec a > img`

The `>` means immediate descendant.

Use `.parent()` after the fact to get the `<a>` again.

Comment: yeah its the same... $("div#sec a>img")

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#sec a>img').parent()
```

could work. Haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sec a:has(> img)')
```

See [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

Comment: He only wants it for direct childs. has() does it for deeper childs too

Answer (score 0):

You could even use [`jQuery.fn.has`](http://api.jquery.com/has/).

```
$('a').has('img');
```

or [`jQuery.fn.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in hand together with [`jQuery.fn.end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

```
$('a').find('img').end();
```